# Problem involving replacing numbers by a product

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, puzzle

I am working on the following problem:

Suppose we have a natural number $c$ that can be expressed as the sum of two other natural numbers, $a$ and $b$: $c = a+b$. If this happens, we say that $c$ is *replaceable* and we replace it by $a\cdot b$. The question is: starting from $c = 22$, can we get to 2021 using a finite number of these steps?

I have tried to find an invariant while performing the replacement step, but I have not been able to succeed. Can anyone give some hint on how to solve it? Maybe it does not even require an invariant, but I am stuck.

Comment: Why do you say "sum" and then replace it with a product?

Comment: This is the way the problem is formulated: $c$ an be replaced by $a\cdot b$ if $a+b=c$, with $a,b,c\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Did you come up with the problem of found it somewhere? Some context would be helpful as well.

Comment: I saw this problem in a math contest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First observe the factorization 2021 = 43.47. Now, write 22 = 1 + 21, replace 22 by 1.21 = 21. Then, 21 = 6 + 15, replace 21 by 6.15 = 90. Finally write 90 = 43 + 47 and replace 90 by 43.47 = 2021.

Answer (score 2):

There's also the not-much-thought approach:

> Observe that we can replace $c$ with $c-1$.

So, we just need to reach a large enough number, then subtract 1 many times.
EG Converting $c > 4 $ to $ 2(c-2)$ as needed.

Notes

- Show that for any starting value $ c > 4$, we can then reach any other natural number
- What if we started with $ c = 1, 2, 3, 4$?